# Debugging Spring RestTemplate on real Android device is really slow

Tags: android, performance, debugging, resttemplate

I have a problem with debbuging an android app on real device (tested on Galaxy mini, and Galaxy Core Plus). App uses Spring RestTemplate for consuming REST services. Normally during app running without debugger the request to server takes about 5sec. But after I try to debug this app (even no breakpoints set up) the app runs really slow. I figured out that the bottleneck is rest request which takes about 50sec instead of 5sec. Does anyone else had similar issues while using RestTemplate in their projects? Or is this something particular in my project configuration. Is there any way to speed up the debugging process (I don't need to debug RestTemplate code at all, just my app classes)?
Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue with debugging on my Android device. There are a few things that my team has done to make debugging take less time.

If you are debugging something unrelated to the server traffic, Then using the Log Cat could save you time. The choice between the Log Cat and the Debugger is going to largely depend on the nature of what you are trying to debug. 
Another thing that could be helpful is unit testing by temporarily disabling the REST Template Code and use hard coded values. In the case of my team, we used REST Template to load in a menu for a restaurant. We would often disable the rest template code and hard code menu values they way they would come in on the server. This allowed us to test internal operations without the time cost of using REST with a debugger.  Once we were confident that the code worked the way we wanted it to, we would replace our hard coded values with the traffic from the server and tested it to verify it all worked the way we expected.

If you are debugging the server traffic, you may find a bad request difficult to track down. You may spend hours tweaking the code and re-running the app on the debugger to track down the issue. If it takes almost a minute per test, then the time will add up quickly. If this is your condition, consider using fiddler.http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler. The way it works is you type in the request URL, headers, and body into the program. Then you simulate the call. If you get a bad request, you don't need to quit out of your app, change some code, and re-run the app to test a change. Instead, you can simply change something in your request and run again. Something that would have taken 5 minutes can be accomplished in 5 seconds. Fiddler will also allow you to see the Raw Request and response if such information is helpful. I've ran into a few bugs where it has been.

Debuggers can be annoyingly slow, especially with Spring REST. Part of that is the price we pay for using a debugger. I would recommend debugging with fiddler. I hope you find something in this helpful.